# Understanding estimator.evaluate and outputting comparisons

Tags: tensorflow

Thanks for your help tensorflow community!

I have a question regarding understanding and visualizing the output of the estimator's evaluate function.

I have a DNNClassifier and have trained it on data with 10 output ranges predictions can go into.

After training and running

`accuracy = classifier.evaluate(input_fn = test_input_fn)['accuracy']`

I see my accuracy as 33.8%.  Which who knows how good that is. (Probably not good)

How can I see the output of each of the comparisons?

As the test_data is ran I would like to see what the estimate is, and what the actual value is.  Basically a side by side of y and y'.

something like: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1] vs [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0] 'false'

Rather than just seeing the aggregated overall accuracy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

So in the event that someone reads the question above, and understands what I was trying to do (view the output of predictions), I have a solution.

The solution is to utilize the .predict() method.

A good example is here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/estimator#classify_new_samples

My code ended up looking like:

```python
predict_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x = {"x": np.array(predict_set.data)}, 
    num_epochs = 1, 
    shuffle = False)

predictions = list(classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn))

print("\n Predictions:")
print(len(predictions))

for p in predictions:
    print(int(p['classes'][0]))
```

which outputs the predictions in a column which I can copy / paste into some spread sheet program to examine my data.